# Error in Java/PHP bridge API

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

I'm using PHP/Java bridge for the gain capital API which you can found [here](http://api.efxnow.com/DEMOWebServices2.8/Service.asmx). But after connecting using [PHP/Java bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) (It is connected properly and i tested that), I'm trying to use the API by creating an object for that and here is the code that i'm using in PHP,

```
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    require_once("http://localhost:8080/jsp/java/Java.inc");

    $application    = java_context()->getServletContext();
    $configFile     = new java("java.util.Properties");
    $epaymentpipe   = new java("com.gain.rateservice.*");
```

But it throws the error as follows.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: CreateInstance failed: new com.gain.rateservice.msg. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gain.rateservice.msg VM: 1.6.0_20@http://java.sun.com/" at: #-10 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1438) #-9 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284) #-8 java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) #-7 java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) #-6 php.java.bridge.Util.classForName(Util.java:1518) #-5 php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.CreateObject(JavaBridge.java:445) #-4 php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequest(Request.java:458) #-3 php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequests(Request.java:500) #-2 php.java.bridge.http.ContextRunner.run(ContextRunner.java:145) #-1 php.java.bridge.ThreadPool$Delegate.run(ThreadPool.java:60) #0 http://localhost:8080/jsp/java/Java.inc(232): java_ThrowExceptionProxyFactory->getProxy(4, 'java.util.Prope...', 'T', false) #1 http://localhost:8080/jsp/java/Java.inc(360): java_Ar in http://localhost:8080/jsp/java/Java.inc on line 195
```

Since i don't know java, i could not able to fix this error. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Here is the screenshot of what i'm getting exactly.

[image]

Comment: Since is a webservice, why can't you use PHP directly?

Comment: Since we need to send each request seperately which will be very slow, i decided to use that

Comment: How is using the java bridge going to make it faster or allow you to create multiple queries?

Comment: @Burhan Khalid - it allows you to manipulate Java objects in PHP, just like importing C/C++ libraries is already done e.g. like CURL which is much better as an imported set of functionality than calling as a webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that Java can't find the class 'com.gain.rateservice.msg'.

It should be included either by:

1) Including it in a classpath that you tell Java about when you run the instance.

2) Including it in the Jar/War you're building and passing to Java.

How to do either depends on exactly how you're invoking or building the Java side of things, but if you're running it from the command line it would be something like:

java -jar HelloWorld.jar -cp /path/to/GainRateserviceFolder/